# Switch can too many packets cause network problems

Tags: networking, switch

What If there are 5 servers connected to a switch: A,B,C,D and E. And what if at the same time A tries to send 500.000 documents to server B and C sends 100.000 documents to A and C and D and E are constantly posting data to the internet. Can this cause packet loss? And what if these servers are posting data and the server will get a network problem, can this happen through to this?

Comment: It depends on the switch. There are switches available who can handle such traffic, and there are switches that cannot.

Comment: how to figure this out

Comment: @bboni That is impossible to explain in the scope of this web-site. You'll need some network-technology background to understand the explanation, and with that background you wouldn't NEED the explanation in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Networks are designed around the assumption that congestion ("too many packets") will happen *routinely*, and that it *will* cause packet loss. Networking technologies are designed to be robust in the face of congestion and packet loss, so that these occurrences should *not* cause problems. In fact, packet loss is the traditional signal to endpoint devices that congestion is happening, so they trigger their congestion control algorithms.

So, yes, too many packets will cause packet loss, but that's just a normal part of network operation and not a problem.